# Book about a boy transported to vintage game show

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This was a book I read in primary school (2016, age 10) and the only thing I remember is that the main character was a boy and I think he was at a mall looking at old TVs before getting sucked into one. Once he was sucked into the TV he was transported to an old game show. I think he could go between the two realities of the TV game show and his actual real life.

I think the book was a old one but I could not tell when. Our teacher would read this book out loud to us during class. I remember they would read off a pdf bc some of us recently got laptops and they allowed us to read ahead/follow along with the teacher so I don’t know the physical cover of the book.

Comment: When were you in primary school?  That would at least give us a no-later-than date for the story.

Comment: @Leek - Someone using a different account with the same name as yours has attempted to edit this question. If that person is you, please merge your new account with the one you used to post this question by following the instructions provided [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). In doing so, you'll regain the ability to edit this question without approval from other users, leave comments within this thread, and mark an answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), if one is posted.

Comment: @LogicDictates It's got to be the same person: the [editing user](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/169973/leek) posted a [question on Literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/25841/17) identical to the [first revision of this post](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/revisions/281515/1). I've retro-approved the edit (not that you and fez were wrong to reject it, just you didn't have enough information to confirm the connection).

Answer (score 4):

Could it have been [Finders Keepers](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/1401863), by Emily Rodda?

In Finders Keepers, Patrick wins the opportunity to be on a game show of the same name that he participates in by crossing "the barrier", by tuning a TV set at a suburban mall to a particular channel at the right time. To play the game, he has to help people find items that were lost on his side of the barrier and bring them back in time for the next episode.